# Google showing static title instead of dynamically set javascript title

Tags: google-search, search-engines, javascript, title

Let's say I have set my title using HTML to "Something - Example" and with Javascript I change the title to "Apple - Example".
When I google my website (after waiting for it to update) or the link gets embedded on websites like Twitter or Discord, it shows the static "Something - Example" title instead of the new title.

Comment: Twitter and discord are not going to be able to show your JS set title.   Their bots that fetch pages for preview purposes don't execute JS.  Googlebot should be able to understand the JS.   How long has been since you updated your title?

Comment: The page that has waited the longest has waited for about a week now without updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A week can be too early for Google to process/render JavaScript and index the final content. (There is no time guarantee from Google on this. Realistically, the JS processing and rendering can take days to weeks.)

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/javascript-seo-basics#how-googlebot-processes-javascript

[image]

At first, Google indexes the HTML that is not modified by JS. You can call it the first phase.

Later, based on resource availability, Google processes (executes) JavaScript in the render queue. Then it indexes the final content. You can call it the second phase.

I think in your case, Google may not have completed the second phase.

Comment: I've seen reports that the second stage of rendering and then indexing the result of that render can take up to 2 months in some cases.